# z-transformation of difference equation

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion, z-transform

Let
$$x_{n+1}-x_{n}=3x_{n}+2$$

I want to find the z-transformation, in the solution, it is stated that

$y(z)=\frac{2}{\frac{1}{z}-3}$
I get a completely different result after multiplying everything by $z^{-n}$, could someone show how to get to the result of the solution?

Comment: The LHS is 0 and there is no $y_n$ term.  Please check your equation.

Comment: @AndyWalls, thanks corrected it

Comment: This is $x_{n+1} = 4x_n + 2$ so certainly the pole should be at $z = 4$, depending on your conventions for the $z$-transform. Can you double-check that the recurrence is as you wrote it and that the claimed $z$-transform is as you wrote it?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan. thank you, I got exactly the same, a pole for z=4. (I double checked everything now and the solution definitely states $y(z)=\frac{2}{\frac{1}{z}-3}$, so therefore I am really confused.

Comment: Well, either the solution's wrong or there's a typo in the problem (or both). If these are online solutions you should know that those things are just written up by random people and can have all sorts of errors in them.

Comment: You need initial conditions as well.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: thank you for your help :)